# Request in destroy Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have the store method and it works well when creating one, the table update increases quantity correctly. but when I delete that Item which I created the table doesn't  update at all, and it must decrease the quantity

```
            $products = $request->items;

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
                $billProduct              = new BillProduct();
                $billProduct->bill_id     = $bill->id;
                $billProduct->product_id  = $products[$i]['item'];
                $billProduct->quantity    = $products[$i]['quantity'];
                
                $billProduct->save();

                Utility::total_quantity('plus',$billProduct->quantity,$billProduct->product_id);
```

and this is destroy the controller

```
             if ($bill->created_by == \Auth::user()->creatorId()) {
                $bill->delete();
                if ($bill->vender_id != 0) {
                    Utility::userBalance('vendor', $bill->vender_id, $bill->getTotal(), 'debit');
                }
               
                BillProduct::where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->delete();
```

and this is a model in which - or + quantity

```
Utility::total_quantity('plus',$billProduct->quantity,$billProduct->product_id);
Utility::total_quantity('munis',$billProduct->quantity,$billProduct->product_id);
```

how can I fix this problem in destroy?? when I put the minus code in destroy methods get server error 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$bill->delete();`, `$bill->vender_id` will set to null. Because of no record found.  What you can do is as I understood,

```
if ($bill->created_by == \Auth::user()->creatorId()) {
   
    $billProducts = BillProduct::where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->get();
    
    # If multiple data, remove from the quantity
    foreach ($billProducts as $billProduct) {
        Utility::total_quantity('minus', $billProduct->quantity, $billProduct->product_id);
    }

    # First delete product then bill
    BillProduct::where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->delete();
    $bill->delete();
}
```

Comment: I am poor in English , sorry about that . and thank you for help

Comment: this is work too <br> $arrg = BillProduct::where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->get()->pluck('quantity');
                    $arrh = BillProduct::where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->get()->pluck('product_id');

                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrg); $i++) {
                        Utility::total_quantity('minus',$arrg[$i], $arrh[$i]);
                    }

Comment: @MehdiBakhtiari there are 100+ ways to write the same code.